# Alternatives to y4mstabilizer; deshaking video

Tags: video, software-rec, mplayer

"Deshaking" means fixing the video captured from camera hold in hands.

Is there open source video deshaker apart from `y4mstabilizer` from `mjpegtools`? Patch for `mencoder` is preferred.

My current command line for processing video looks like:

```
mplayer  video_from_camera.avi -nosound -vo yuv4mpeg:file=/dev/stdout -really-quiet | y4mstabilizer -n -a 0.8 -r 30 -s 100 | mplayer -cache 1000 /dev/stdin -noconsolecontrols -vf crop=500:380:70:50,denoise3d=3:3:5:5 -vo yuv4mpeg:file=temporary.yuv
```

y4mstabilizer is itself very unstable and often crashes (and it didn't work at all until I have patched memory allocation in it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ffmpeg` with the same filter as in `transcode`:

```
# create deshaking profile, with a preview
ffmpeg -i inputvideo.mkv -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf vidstabdetect=show=1:result=inputvideo.trf -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 0 -an -f matroska - | ffplay  -

# preview the transformed video
ffmpeg -i inputvideo.mkv -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf vidstabtransform=input=inputvideo.trf:smoothing=5  -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 0 -an -f matroska -  | ffplay -
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `transcode` with "stabilize" and "transform" plugin pair. http://www.transcoding.org/

```
transcode -i temporary1.yuv -J  stabilize=maxshift=100=fieldsize=20 -y null,null -o /dev/null
transcode -i temporary1.yuv -J transform=smooth=50,denoise3d=luma=3:chroma=3:luma_strength=5:chroma_strength=5 -y yuv4mpeg -o temporary2.yuv
```